# What's the runtime complexity of array::len in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, time-complexity

What's the runtime complexity of the `len` method for primitive arrays in Rust? I understand that it's constant for `Vector` and `String`, however each of those types keep track of their length and I can't find any documentation on whether that's the case for arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive arrays have a constant length so it is safe to assume that the size of an array can be calculated during compilation (a compile-time constant)

Given:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
println!("Length: {}", array.len());
```

Debug builds give:

```
callq   alloc::slice::<impl [T]>::len
movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
movq    core::fmt::num::<impl core::fmt::Display for usize>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
```

Debug builds appear to delegate the responsibility to the `len` method of a slice.

However, release builds, as expected, calculate a constant during compilation, push it directly into the stack and use that instead:

```
movq    $5, (%rsp)
movq    core::fmt::num::<impl core::fmt::Display for usize>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
```

Comment: Removed my comment where the calculation was based purely on bytes ... I was thinking at a compiler level there and it really made no sense in context with the question.

Comment: Thanks! And so I assume that primitive arrays don't carry a constant associated with their size?

Comment: No they don't. The length is known at compile time and this value is baked directly into the generated assembly (for Release builds).

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) says: _A fixed-size array, denoted `[T; N]`, for the element type, `T`, and the non-negative **compile-time constant** size, `N`._